# Synonym: Medium or soothsayer

Tags: pronunciation, single-word-requests, synonyms

I don't know if many of you watched the new Matt Damon movie *Hereafter*. Near the end of the movie, the little boy who lost his twin brother meets Matt Damon in the Book reading room, and says something like: "Hey, I know you, you are a sight[?]". Indeed, I'm missing the word between the brackets, how did he refer to a medium?

He said something like *sightkey*, *sightkick*, *sightsikh*, but none of these are the correct words, I've tried looking it up on the Internet but I'm truly unable to come across this synonym.

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen this movie yet, but given your description I guess he said **psychic**.

Here is the [definition from Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/psychic_3):

> a person who has a special mental
>   ability, for example being able to
>   know what will happen in the future or
>   what people are thinking

Comment: Beat me to it by 11 seconds.

Comment: AAaaaah I know this word ! Just didn't know how to correctly pronounce it ! Nice shot, thank you very much.

Comment: BTW, from Wikipedia: [Matt Damon as George Lonegan, an American factory worker and "a reluctant psychic ... who can speak to the dead but prefers not to".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereafter_%28film%29#Cast)

Comment: Yeah right ! I saw that already, but I was pronouncing the "ch" of psychic as in "chair" :P

Comment: @RegDwight small question why did you turn "Matt Damon's movie" to "Matt Damon movie" while correcting my mistakes ? I don't understand why I should put the ' there. Thank you :)

Comment: @Miloud: because it is preceded by "the new". The article "the" and possession don't mix well. Just replace "Matt Damon's" with any possessive pronoun and see for yourself: "the new his movie", "the new my movie", etc. don't work. You can say "my/his new movie" or "the new movie (of mine/his)". (By taking away the possessive "'s", I turned "Matt Damon" into an adjective, so it can stay where it is without interfering with the rest. Alternatively, I could have changed it into "Matt Damon's new movie".)